# Pin different panels to main panel using wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have an option 'Histogram' in the menu bar of my main panel and whenever it is clicked a function Hist(), will be called which plots a histogram in a new panel. There might be multiple histograms that can be created. I want these panels to be pinned(minimized in the main panel) to the main panel like in adobe photoshop interface. 
Thanks.
Link for example:
https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/technology/tutorials/graphics/illustratorcs2/introduction_clip_image002_0000.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like AUI_MDI. It's a little ugly in wxPython which is why there is a newer version of it included that was rewritten from scratch in Python. I would recommend that. It is the wx.lib.agw.aui library. You can read about it at the following:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/AuiNotebook%20%28AGW%29
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.aui.framemanager.AuiManager.html
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.aui.auibook.AuiNotebook.html

You can also see an example in the wxPython demo package.

Comment: Thanks mike, After going through this I am using tabs of notebooks and show each plot in each tab. But how can I get the active tab number?
I posted the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180348/how-can-i-get-tab-number-of-active-tab-in-wxnotebook